# java-script function is called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a service which on click saves the Facebook information of a user to the database.Now the problem is that my services are being called twice. I can not figure out why it is behaving in such manner. Please Help.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jgrowl.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jgrowl.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fb.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Registration Method</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="button" value="Login With Facebook" id="fb-auth">   </th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

fb.js

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  xfbml      : true,
                  version    : 'v2.1',
                  status     : true, 
                  cookie     : true,
                  oauth      : true
                });




                function updateButton(response) {
                    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

                    if (response.authResponse) { // in case if we are logged in
                        var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                           var socialMediaRegistration={};
                           socialMediaRegistration['name']=response.name;
                           socialMediaRegistration['profileId']=response.id;
                           socialMediaRegistration['email']=response.email;
                           socialMediaRegistration['socialPlatform']="Facebook";
                           var mydata={};
                           mydata['socialMediaRegistration']=socialMediaRegistration;
                           submitData(mydata);

                        });

                        button.onclick = function() {
                            FB.logout(function(response) {
                                window.location.reload();
                            });
                        };
                    } else { // otherwise - dispay login button
                        button.onclick = function() {
                            FB.login(function(response) {
                                if (response.authResponse) {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            }, {scope:'email,public_profile'});
                        }
                    }
                }

                // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
                FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
            };

              (function(d, s, id){
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
               }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol + 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                if (document.getElementById('fb-root')) 
                    {document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);};

            }());
function submitData(data){
alert("this is below the submitdata");
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.jGrowl.defaults.position = 'center';
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://localhost:8080/components/services/saveSocialMedia",//use ur service
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             crossDomain: true,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                 $.unblockUI();
                 $.blockUI({ message: null });
                 $.jGrowl('Application Reference: '+data["Id"]+' is created. <br/><br/>Have a nice day!', {
                    sticky: true,
                    header: 'Request Submitted Successfully!',
                    life: 5000,
                    speed:  'slow',
                    animateOpen: { 
                        height: "show",
                        width: "show"
                    },
                    animateClose: { 
                        height: "hide",
                        width: "show"
                    },
                    close: function(e,m,o) {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        //$("#ApplicationRequestForm")[0].reset();
                    },
                    click: function(msg) {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        //$("#ApplicationRequestForm")[0].reset();
                        $("div.jGrowl").jGrowl("close");
                        return true;
                    }
                }); 
             },

             error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                 $.unblockUI();
                 $.blockUI({ message: null });
                 $.jGrowl('Please try again after sometime.', {
                    sticky: true,
                    header: 'Ouch! An Unexptected Error Occurred.',
                    life: 5000,
                    speed:  'slow',
                    animateOpen: { 
                        height: "show",
                        width: "show"
                    },
                    animateClose: { 
                        height: "hide",
                        width: "show"
                    },
                    close: function(e,m,o) {
                        $.unblockUI();
                    },
                    click: function(msg) {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        $("div.jGrowl").jGrowl("close");
                        return true;
                    }
                }); 
                console.log(jqXHR);
             }
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use CORS, some of your requests get [preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). According to the docs:

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.  Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.  In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
> - It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)

You are using the POST method, but your content type is set to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, so the browser will first send a request with the `OPTIONS` method, and *then* it will send your `POST`.

And, for the browser to allow the `POST`, the `OPTIONS` response must contain certain headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

These tell your browser that the `http://foo.example` is an allowed origin, that `POST`, `GET`, and `OPTIONS`, are allowed methods, and that `X-PINGOTHER` is an allowed header.

So, your service is being called twice because it's being preflighted automatically by the browser.